# how to get a of list schemas in specific database in DB2

Tags: database, db2

how to get a of list schemas in specific database in DB2.
I am trying to get list of specific schemas in particular database

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
select schemaname from syscat.schemata
```

The catalog view [SYSCAT.SCHEMATA](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001059.html) holds the schema information. Here is the [overview of all DB2 LUW catalog views](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011297.html) in case you need other information as well.

Answer (score 2):

The DB2 zOS schemas can be found with this query

```
select distinct schemaname
from (
  select creator from sysibm.systables
  union all
  select schema from sysibm.sysdatatypes
  union all
  select schema from sysibm.sysroutines
  union all
  select schema from sysibm.systriggers
) schemata(schemaname)
```

Comment: You might need to quote the "schema" keyword in some Db2 instances